# No rule to make target - Makefille

Tags: makefile

I need some help understanding why my makefile is not picking up the rule to convert my .c files in .o.

```
NAME        = push_swap

INCLUDES    = -I includes -I $(LIBFT_DIR)/includes/

LIBFT_DIR   = libft/

CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

DIR_SRCS    = srcs
DIR_OBJS    = objs

SRCS        = push_swap.c utils_1.c
OBJS        = $(subst $(DIR_SRCS), $(DIR_OBJS), $(SRCS:.c=.o))



all:        $(NAME)

$(OBJF):
            @mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJS)

$(DIR_OBJS)/%.o :   $(DIR_SRCS)/%.c | $(OBJF)
            @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

$(LIBFT):
            @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR)

$(NAME):    $(OBJS) $(LIBFT)
            @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

clean:
            rm -f $(OBJS)

fclean:     clean
            rm -f $(NAME)

re:         fclean all

.PHONY:     all clean fclean re bonus
```

I get the following error:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'push_swap.o', needed by 'push_swap'.  Stop.`

It's the first time I'm adding folders to my makefile and maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Thank you all for your help.

I ended up changing a few things because I was having a hard time doing it the other way.

```
NAME        = push_swap

INCLUDES    = -I includes -I $(LIBFT_DIR)/includes/

LIBFT_DIR   = libft/

CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

DIR_SRCS    = srcs/
DIR_OBJS    = objs/

SRCS_FILES  = push_swap utils_1

SRCS        = $(addprefix $(DIR_SRCS), $(addsuffix .c, $(SRCS_FILES)))
OBJS        = $(addprefix $(DIR_OBJS), $(addsuffix .o, $(SRCS_FILES)))

all:        $(NAME)

$(NAME):    $(OBJS) $(LIBFT)
            @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_DIR)libft.a

$(DIR_OBJS)%.o :    $(DIR_SRCS)%.c $(OBJF)
            @mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJS)
            @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

$(LIBFT):
            @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR)

clean:
            rm -f $(OBJS)
            rm -r $(DIR_OBJS)

fclean:     clean
            rm -f $(NAME)

re:         fclean all

.PHONY:     all clean fclean re
```

Like this it runs perfectly.

Comment: Does push_swap.c exist in the source directory?

Comment: You will note, you don't actually use the variable `SRCS` anywhere in the makefile (as I mentioned in my comment below, you don't need it).

Comment: One other thing: you should _never_ use plain `make` in a makefile recipe.  You should **always** use the variable `$(MAKE)` instead.

Comment: Oh and one final thing: it's almost always a bad idea to use `@` to hide the compile commands that make is running.  At least, you should use a method like http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ to make it easy to see them.  Many makefile questions on StackOverflow might have been avoided if the author hadn't been hiding the commands make was running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
SRCS = push_swap.c utils_1.c
```

The line:

```
OBJS        = $(subst $(DIR_SRCS), $(DIR_OBJS), $(SRCS:.c=.o))
```

is replacing the $(DIR_SRCS) (`srcs`) value with $(DIR_OBJS) (`objs`), BUT the SRC values does have `objs` in it so:

```
OBJS        = push_swap.o utils_1.o
```

And so not finding a rule for it.

Try changing to:

```
SRCS = $(DIR_SRCS)/push_swap.c $(DIR_SRCS)/utils_1.c
```

Comment: An alternative to this is to leave `SRCS` the way it is, then set `OBJS = $(addprefix $(DIR_OBJS)/,$(SRCS))`.  There's no real need to have `SRCS` set to the full path.